# how to apply both italic and normal fonts in the same label in phylogenetic tree in ggtree

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggtree, ggtext

I want A in italic, and CBS in normal.
I think ggtext might be useful, but I got an error.
here is an example:

```
tree<-read.tree(text="(A,(B,C));")
labs=c("*A*CBS","B","C")
tree$tip.label<-labs
ggtree(tree)+ geom_tiplab(align=T) + geom_richtext()

error: geom_rich_text requires the following missing aesthetics: label
```

I also tried

```
ggtree(tree)+ aes(label=labs)+geom_tiplab(align=T) + geom_richtext()
error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (5): label
```

but the rich text I need is in three tip labels, not all five labels (tip and node)
does anyone know how to add the label aesthetics (as tip label)?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: What you want to do would have to be added as a feature to the ggtree package. The `geom_tiplab()` function would need a markdown option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `parse = T` argument combined with [mathematical annotation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/grDevices/html/plotmath.html):

```
library(ggtree)
library(ggtext)
tree<-read.tree(text="(A,(B,C));")
labs=c("paste(italic('A'),'CBS')","B","C")
tree$tip.label<-labs
ggtree(tree)+ geom_tiplab(align=T,parse=T)
```

[image]